# Red dot in Adobe Creative Cloud macOS menu bar icon

Tags: macos, notifications, icon, menu-bar, adobe

I have installed Adobe Creative Cloud on my MacBook. This causes an Adobe CC icon to be added to the macOS menu bar.

Frequently, this Adobe CC icon has a red notification circle:

[image: Adobe Creative Cloud menu bar icon]
[image: Adobe Creative Cloud menu bar icon red dot]

When I click on the red-dotted menu bar icon, the normal Creative Cloud window pops up. No apparent notification or needed update is shown. In the window, neither the "bell" or "cloud" icon are given any special dot treatment to show that something is happening or needs alerting. I don't know why the red dot exists. There are various [threads](https://community.adobe.com/t5/download-install-discussions/notification-badge-for-cc/m-p/11029655) on the Adobe CC forum asking this same question about the red dot, but no good information or answers.

1. What state does the red notification dot represent? Why is the red dot shown?
2. How can I prevent the red dot from being shown on the Adobe CC macOS menu bar icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Adobe Support Document](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/notifications.html), you can disable the red dot by turning off Notifications.

> #### How to turn notifications on or off
>
> 1. Open the Creative Cloud desktop app. (Select the [image] icon in your Windows taskbar or the macOS menu bar.)
> 2. Select the **Account** icon in the upper right, and then select Preferences.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. In the left sidebar, select **Notifications**.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Select or deselect the types of notifications you want to receive. Then select **Done**.

Works for me.

Comment: Awesome. I don't think these notification preferences used to exist. I've turned off the notifications and will monitor if I ever see another red dot.